# cannot handle model.save error and return to FE

Tags: node.js, mongoose, error-handling, event-handling, mongoose-models

I'm trying to save an item to DB using Mongoose and return the saved item or the error to the client.
When making a postman call with a duplicate document i expect to get an error of duplicated, get to the 'catch' statement and retrieve a 500 status code and a message. However, i always get to 'then' with result undefined and status code 200.
I also tried to change the 'throw' to 'return' but with no success. Where i'm wrong?

Route:

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const schema = Joi.object({
    // id: Joi.number().required(),
    name: Joi.string().min(3).required(),
    description: Joi.string().optional(),
    categoryID: Joi.number().required(),
    // ingredients: Joi.array().optional(),
    price: Joi.number().required(),
    vegan: Joi.boolean().required(),
    special: Joi.boolean().required(),
    img: Joi.string(),
  });
  let result = schema.validate(req.body);

  if (result.error) {
    res.status(400).send(result.error);
    return;
  }

  let menu = new Menu();
  const {
    // id,
    name,
    description,
    categoryID,
    ingredients,
    price,
    vegan,
    special,
    // img,
  } = req.body;

  // menu.id = id;
  menu.name = name;
  menu.categoryID = categoryID;
  menu.description = description;
  menu.ingredients = ingredients;
  menu.price = price;
  menu.vegan = vegan;
  menu.special = special;
  // menu.img = img;

  MenuService.saveMenuItem(menu)
    .then((result) => {
      return res.json(result);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    });
});
```

Service:

```
async function saveMenuItem(menuItem) {
  await menuItem.save((err, item) => {
    if (err) throw new Error(err.message);
    return item;
  });
}

module.exports.saveMenuItem = saveMenuItem;
```

[This is the route.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg195.png)

[This is the service.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sxgW.png)

Comment: Did you add validation on mongoose schema? on which property duplicate validation is present?

Comment: Yep, in the schema i have 'unique' on 'name'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may should try this:

```
async function saveMenuItem(menuItem) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      menuItem.save((err, item) => {
         if (err) reject(err.message);
         resolve(item);
})
}
```

Comment: it works! but, this is the best practice? thats how it should be?
Thank you very much!